# List of Class with Property of T

Tags: c#, list, class, generics

I am trying to create a list of a class with the property with T:

```
class Test<T> where T : IClass, new()
{
    public T Actor { get { return new T(); } }
    public eEnum { get; set; }
    public String Str { get; set; }
}
```

The above is an example class, how can I create a list of the above class?

I have tried the below with no avail:

```
List<Test<IClass>> list = new List<IClass>();
```

Is there a way to achieve creating a list like I am trying to generate?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `List<Test<IClass>> list = new List<Test<IClass>>();`?

Comment: Yeah, you would need to have the right hand initializer match the variable type on the left. Though I do wonder, the `new()` you have in the Type Parameter constraints looks like you are requiring a new instance of `IClass` but you really just need the type. Since your `Actor` is handling the newing up, I would suggest removing the `new()` contstraint.

Comment: @TurnerBass the [`new()` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) specifies that the type `T` must have a public parameterless constructor (which enables the `Actor` method to call `new T()`)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But still the list initialization looks like the main problem

Comment: @TurnerBass If the OP removed the `new()` constraint, the class wouldn't compile anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have added the generic type constraint `new()`, you must provide a type that has a public parameterless constructor. An interface doesn't have a constructor. Therefore you must indicate a class. E.g.

```
List<Test<MyActorClass>> list = new List<Test<MyActorClass>>();
```

Or drop this `new()` constraint and instead add a generic factory method

```
class Test
{
    public T CreateActor<T>()
        where T : IClass, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public MyEnum eEnum { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}
```

And simply create a list `List<Test>`.

Or supply a concrete actor type through constructor injection:

```
class Test
{
    public Test(IClass actor)
    {
        Actor = actor;
    }

    public IClass Actor { get; }
    public MyEnum eEnum { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}
```

---

An even more advanced construction is to use a non-generic abstract base class and to derive a generic one  from it

```
abstract class Test
{
    private IClass _actor;
    public IClass Actor
    {
        get {
            if (_actor == null) {
                _actor = CreateActor();
            }
            return _actor;
        }
    }

    public MyEnum eEnum { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }

    protected abstract IClass CreateActor(); // We implement it in the generic class.
}

class Test<T> : Test
    where T : IClass, new()
{
    public new T Actor // Hides inherited member.
    {
        get { return (T)base.Actor;  }
    }

    protected override IClass CreateActor()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

The list would again be of type `List<Test>`. This has the advantage that you can add different types of classes deriving from `Test` to the list and at the same time you have a strongly typed actor when accessing it through a concrete  `Test<T>`.